# Get all 90 days before today with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I want to have all 90 days before today as an array. I couldn't any solution in StackOverflow or Google.

```js
const now = new Date(); 
const daysBefore = now.setDate(priorDate.getDate() - 90);
```

My expected result is an array of 90 days before today:

```
const days = [
 '2021-06-03T05:45:36.685Z',
 '2021-06-02T05:45:36.685Z',
 '2021-06-01T05:45:36.685Z',
 '2021-05-30T05:45:36.685Z',
 ...
]
```

Comment: what is your expected result?

Comment: In what order? Ascending or descending?

Comment: The order does not matter @Phil

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create an array of dates by creating a new array of length 90 and mapping each entry to a new date that is *now* minus the *index* number of days

```js
const now = new Date()
const length = 90

const days = Array.from({ length }, (_, days) => {
  let day = new Date(now) // clone "now"
  day.setDate(now.getDate() - days) // change the date
  return day
})

console.log(days)
```

This creates an array of `Date` instances starting with *now* and working back for 90 days (descending order).

See also [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

Comment: Did not know about that second argument. Now I gotta go simplify about 1000 list-creation routines.

Comment: Now I'm wondering how somebody thought to return milliseconds from epoch from `Date#setDate` is a good idea.